# Random sounds in discord.js

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, discord.js

I'm programming a discord bot using discord.js. I want to make a random sound player!
What am I doing wrong? Can you help me?

```
case 'ps':
            var voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel
                voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
                number = 5;
            var random = Math.floor (Math.random() * (number - 1 + 1 )) + 1;
            var rs = ( {files: [__dirname + '/Library/folder/' + "sound" + " (" + random + ")" + ".jpg"]} );
            const dispatcher = connection.playFile(rs);
                dispatcher.on('end', end => voiceChannel.leave());
            })
        break;
```

There aren't any errors in terminal.

Comment: Can you add a brief description of the problem please?

Answer (score 3):

Your issue would be the fact you're trying to get an image, not an audio file.

replace `.jpg` in `var rs = ( {files: [__dirname + '/Library/folder/' + "sound" + " (" + random + ")" + ".jpg"]} );` to whatever audio file extension you're using: `mp3`, `wav`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are trying to get an Audio file with the extension ".jpg" in :

```
var rs = ( {files: [__dirname + '/Library/folder/' + "sound" + " (" + random + ")" + ".jpg"]} );
```

replace `.jpg` with an audio extension, *.mp3, .wav, etc...*